# is it posible to have abstract in second page on latex?

Tags: latex

is it possible to have abstract in second page on latex?
i have used :

```
\begin{abstract}
text
\end{abstract}
```

but it always is played on the first page, do any one have a quick fix for it?

Comment: Yes it is possible. To tell you how, please add a [mre]

Comment: I suggest adding `\newpage` before the `\begin{abstract}....`, but show us a minimal exemple so we can answer better ;)

Comment: At least which documentclass do you use?? Add a MWE as in the comment above! :)